# what is the max number you can set for plugin.tt_news.limit

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I have a site where I want to show all my non archived articles on the one page.  What is the max limit you can set for this?  It seems to never show more than 40 articles even if I have the below typoscript in the constants and I have over 100 I want to show on the one list?

```
    plugin.tt_news.limit = 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default TypoScript value is 7. The number must be in the range from 0 to **1000**. If not, the plugin will set the limit to 50.

In other words, your value of 200 should be fine. Taking into account your setup, do check that...

1. ...if the TypoScript value of the `plugin.tt_news.limit` constant is set in the root page, it is not being overridden by a value set on the page displaying the news or some parent page.
2. ...there is no value set in a TypoScript setup(!). The default setup is `plugin.tt_news.limit = {$plugin.tt_news.limit}` - this means that the setup uses the constant value. You might have accidently set it to e.g. `plugin.tt_news.limit = xx` which means that the constant value would never be used.
3. ...there is no limit set in the plugin content element as it would override the TypoScript value.

Comment: news list is not working perfectly for example  if you set news list limit 5 then   it will not display first 5 news form list so it was mistakes in limit function

Comment: @MaunilPrajapati I'm afraid my answer is too old and might not apply to current version of TYPO3 or tt_news. It was working at that time but many things has probably changed since then.